# What programming language can be used to code in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino

I'm in beginner level of learning Arduino. I want to know what `programming language` used in Arduino?

I've followed tutorials and tried some codes and then got outputs such as `blink LED`, `knight_rider` ,`measure distance using ultrasound sensor` & etc.

Here is a peice of code I learned in the tutorial for measure distance using ultrasound sensor.

```
  `Serial.print`(inches);
  `Serial.print`("in \t ");
  `Serial.print`(cm);
  `Serial.println`("cm");
```

When I searched google, It says `C/C++` are used in Arduino. I have learnt `C`and `C#`. But as far I know there is no function called `println` in `C` language. It confuse me what language is this?

Comment: The language is C++. The stdlib is custom though. So its only _partly_ C++.

Comment: You are better served by asking Arduino questions on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Arduino FAQ:

> Can I program the Arduino board in C? In fact, you already are; **the
>   Arduino language is merely a set of C/C++ functions** that can be called
>   from your code. Your sketch undergoes minor changes (e.g. automatic
>   generation of function prototypes) and then is passed directly to a
>   C/C++ compiler

From Wikipedia:

> **The Arduino IDE supports the languages C and C++** using special rules
>   of code structuring.

You can define your own functions in pretty much any programming language. That there is a function named println doesn't mean that it isn't C++ anymore.

Comment: > "You can define your own functions in pretty much any programming language" is a bit misleading. You should write your code in C / C++.  println or any other provided method/function is written in C++.

Comment: I'm still a 1st year undergraduate so I know only `C` and `C#`. That means do I have to self learn `C++` to do  an Arduino project? Or else can I do it by using `C`?

Comment: You can write your own code using pure C without any C++ features, but you will almost certainly have to learn some C++ as you will be interacting with libraries written using C++.

Comment: @datafiddler of course you cannot mix programming languages in a C/C++ environment. his conclusion that it's not C++ because he doesn't know the println function was just wrong. and that's true for almost all programming languages. I don't find this misleading

Comment: @Piglet: (after rereading your answer) you're right, of course. sorry.
@Eranga Madhushani: `Serial.println("Hello");` is c++. (`Serial` is an object of class `HardwareSerial`, which provides a method `println`) Have fun learning c++ basics.